# compiling for the MIPS II ISA

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, mips

Can anyone tell me how to compile `Protobuf` for `MIPS` platform.

I am trying to compile the wince ported `libprotobuf` code on **visual studio 2005** but it is throwing me following errors:

```
Z:\protobuf-2.5.0\src\google/protobuf/stubs/platform_macros.h(63) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Host architecture was not detected as supported by protobuf
```

Comment: Could you eloborate more on how you're trying to build this library? The compiler options you're using, etc.

Comment: compiler options:
/O2 /Os /I "Z:\protobuf-2.5.0\src" /I "Z:\protobuf-2.5.0\vsprojects" /I "../src;.;./wince_port" /I "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\ce\include" /I "C:\Program Files\Windows CE Tools\wce600\DbAu13xx\Include\Mipsii" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WIN32_WCE=0x600" /D "UNDER_CE" /D "WINCE" /D "_LIB" /D "MIPS" /D "_MIPS_" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /FD /EHsc /fp:fast /GR- /Fo"DbAu13xx (MIPSII)\Debug/" /Fd"DbAu13xx (MIPSII)\Debug/vc80.pdb" /nologo /c /TP /QMmips2 /QMFPE

Comment: Linker options:
/OUT:"Z:\protobuf-2.5.0\vsprojects\DbAu13xx (MIPSII)\Debug\libprotobuf.exe" /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Windows CE Tools\wce600\DbAu13xx\Lib\MIPSII" /MANIFEST:NO /NODEFAULTLIB:"oldnames.lib" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT coredll.lib corelibc.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib commctrl.lib